# Amazon Selling Partner API - Refund list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazonsellercentral

I want to retrieve some information from my amazon seller account to create my own application by processing the data extrapolated from the API by [Seller Partner API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/welcome). I can get my inventory, orders, even finished, in progress or canceled shipments. I would like to have a summary of the refunds issued by my customers in order to process this information as well, but I'm having quite a bit of difficulty finding the right service.

I started with the idea of receiving the "order returned" information from the order list, but as far as I understand there is no response property that gives me that information. So I found the [Report](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/reports-api-v2021-06-30-reference) services, including return reports, which queries the list of reports already carried out in reference to refunds, only that even if I have had refunds, I always get an empty list of elements.